# Tag synonym for phpdocumentor

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, synonym-request

The [phpDocumentor](http://www.phpdoc.org/) (like JavaDoc, but for PHP) is also commonly known as `phpdoc` (for instance in it's url and the command's actual name. Both [phpdocumentor](/questions/tagged/phpdocumentor) and [phpdoc](/questions/tagged/phpdoc) exist.

I suggest to make [phpdocumentor](/questions/tagged/phpdocumentor) the 'master', as that's the official name of the program?

Currently even the tag wikis are practically the same:

> phpdocumentor is Documentation Generator for PHP written in PHP.

vs

> phpDocumentor (phpdoc) is an automatic code-documentation tool for PHP, based on Javadoc.

Answer (score -1):

phpDocumentor is a product.

"phpdoc" is the name of the comment format that it *and other products* use.

They are not synonyms.  They're *related*, but they are *not* the same thing.

Comment: It is not one or the other, both are true. The point is, on stackoverlfow both unofficially (if I look at the topics and how the tag is used) and officially (the wiki about phpdoc says **phpDocumentor (phpdoc) is an automatic code-documentation tool for PHP, based on Javadoc.**), it is not used as the comment format, but as short for phpDocumentor. phpdoc is according to wikipedia, not maintained since 2000. It does refer to phpdocumentor and doxygen: but does the latter even use the word "phpdoc" for the format?